# Neyman-Pearson lemma equivalent for undefined pdf

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

The Likelihood Ratio Test is the most powerful test for the simple hypotheses $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ by virtue of the Neyman-Pearson lemma.

However, the implicit assumption in the lemma is that the densities $f(x;\theta_0)$ and $f(x;\theta_1)$ exist.

Is there an equivalent most powerful test when the densities/likelihoods do not exist?

Comment: Do you have an example in mind ? What kind of example for which there is no density ?

Comment: Multivariate normal where $\Sigma^{-1}$ is not defined

Comment: In this case the problem can be transformed to get the case of a density Say, for example, you have $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ with a linear relation $X_3=aX_1+bX_2$ and $(X_1,X_2)$ is free of linear realtions. The distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$ completely determines the distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, and $(X_1,X_2)$ is not singular.
But there also is a density of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. You are free to choose the *dominating measure* for the likelihood. Here there exists a density of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure on the hyperplane in which this random vector takes its values.